# Exercise 39 from 'Learn Ruby the Hard Way' - Not working

Tags: ruby

This is from *[exercise 39 from Learn Ruby The Hardway](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex39.html)*

I am currently getting this error.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': /home/lost/Dropbox/Ruby/Dict.rb:45: formal argument cannot be a constant (SyntaxError)
  def Dict.set(aDict, Key, value)
                         ^
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require
    from ex39_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

You can find my code *[here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/kamalsnas/dnzGL/ex39_testrb)*

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your arguments in `Dict` module.

```
def Dict.set(aDict, Key, value)
```

should be:

```
def Dict.set(aDict, key, value)
```

Comment: Sigh,.... something so simple thanks for all your help greatly appreciated.. 7 hours of Ruby straight will do that do you..